# How to design an "event or calendar" related database (I am trying to invent a design system tied to keys)

Tags: database-design, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Technologies that I will use are : **GAE Datastore and Objectify**. My database is related to events and places (maybe some experts that has already designed a database similar to google calendar, or facebook event etc... could help me).

IMO, I need to design my database in the way that I should really quickly load and find the events. So I have no idea if what I will explain is a pattern that other people use...and if you can tell me if it is a good idea or not...

The trick is that, **I assume that the keys in the datastore will be orderered in the *alphabetical* way** (I think I have read it is possible to do that...).

I want to create a key (String) for each new event created, that will be composed such has :

**[year_month_day] [hour_minute] [country_city_zone_local] [eventName]**

*example of keys stored in the datastore:*

[201304012200_fr_paris_quartierLatin_latinNightclub_superFiesta1]
[201304022200_fr_paris_quartierLatin_latinNightclub_superFiesta2]
[201304032200_fr_paris_quartierLatin_latinNightclub_superFiesta3]
[201304042200_fr_paris_quartierLatin_latinNightclub_superFiesta4]

In the example above, there is 4 events happening 4 consecutives days in the same local (latinNightClub).

Now, let's say that I have **millions of events, in 50 countries**, and I should quickly load the events happening between DAY_1 (2013/04/02) and DAY_2 (2013/04/04) . With my idea, I should fetch all the results for the key starting by 20130402....., 20130403... and 20130404....I am currently thinking that if all the keys are ordered alphabetically, this solution will be the faster possible.

*Question 1* : Is it a good idea to design my database like this ? And is it possible to do it with the technologies mentionned ?

*Question 2* : In the key, I also have included the informations relative to the country and the local where the event happens...because, if the user just want the events that are happening in the "latinNightClub" so I can also fetch quickly the results (due to the fact that the keys are alphabetically ordered...) So is it also a good idea ?

As far as I am concerned, it is hard to do the first step, your help could be really great ! If I am totally wrong, please, feel free to give me any link that should help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible idea.

You will inevitably need to change the properties of an event, and changing a key value is nigh near impossible in a real-world schema. Google "natural vs synthetic keys" - this debate has been rehashed millions of times in traditional RDBMSes and the same lesson applies here.

Just create a multi-property index on the fields you are trying to search on. Problem sovled.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the quick answer, I need to read a lot (keeping in mind what you explained about multi-properties...) I have seen your site: www.voo.st/events...To be honest, I would like to see the code/design/architecture of this project to inspire me...but not everything is possible in this world...Tks again.

Comment: If you have any specific questions about Voost, post them to the Objectify Google Group and I will answer. I'm pretty open about it.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to compile the MOTOMAPIA project...I have used Eclipse and imported a maven project...but in the build-path, batchfb-2.1.3.jar is missing. What should I do (I am also new to maven) ?

Comment: Oops, that's my fault. I haven't pushed batchfb 2.1.3 to maven central yet. I will do that tonight.